# Error occurred while sending email using spring frame work

Tags: java, spring, smtp

I'm trying to send an email using spring framework. Im getting the following errors while trying to run the code. I use intellij IDE.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The 'original' message argument cannot be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:112)
at org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage.<init>(SimpleMailMessage.java:73)
at com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.SimpleOrderManager.placeOrder(SimpleOrderManager.java:34)
at com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.SimpleOrderManager.main(SimpleOrderManager.java:48)
```

This is my code

```
package com.howtodoinjava.demo.model;

//import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;
```

public class SimpleOrderManager {

```
private MailSender mailSender;
private SimpleMailMessage templateMessage;

//public String order;
//public String customer;

public void setMailSender(MailSender mailSender) {
    this.mailSender = mailSender;
}

public void setTemplateMessage(SimpleMailMessage templateMessage) {
    this.templateMessage = templateMessage;
}

public void placeOrder() {

    // Do the business calculations...

    // Call the collaborators to persist the order...

    // Create a thread safe "copy" of the template message and customize it
    SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(this.templateMessage);
    msg.setTo("mygmail@gmail.com");
    msg.setText("Message");
    try{
        this.mailSender.send(msg);
    }
    catch (MailException ex) {
        // simply log it and go on...
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void main(String []args){
     SimpleOrderManager obj = new SimpleOrderManager();
     obj.placeOrder();
}
```

}

I have hard coded the message and email address for now.

edit:

Now I get this error After removing this.templateMessage.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.SimpleOrderManager.placeOrder(SimpleOrderManager.java:32)
at com.howtodoinjava.demo.model.SimpleOrderManager.main(SimpleOrderManager.java:42)
```

This is my spring-servlet.xml file

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.howtodoinjava.demo" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="mail.mycompany.com"/>
</bean>

<!-- this is a template message that we can pre-load with default state -->
<bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from" value="customerservice@mycompany.com"/>
    <property name="subject" value="Your order"/>
</bean>

<bean id="orderManager" class="com.mycompany.businessapp.support.SimpleOrderManager">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're following [official Spring tutorial](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mail.html), you forgot to add beans definitions.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="mail.mycompany.com"/>
</bean>

<!-- this is a template message that we can pre-load with default state -->
<bean id="templateMessage" class="org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage">
    <property name="from" value="customerservice@mycompany.com"/>
    <property name="subject" value="Your order"/>
</bean>

<bean id="orderManager" class="com.mycompany.businessapp.support.SimpleOrderManager">
    <property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender"/>
    <property name="templateMessage" ref="templateMessage"/>
</bean>
```

In your code, `this.templateMessage` is `null` which results in exception.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong constructor, use:

```
SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage();
```

instead

```
SimpleMailMessage msg = new SimpleMailMessage(this.templateMessage);
```

and you also will need to create mailSender:

```
private JavaMailSenderImpl createMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
    javaMailSender.setUsername(configuration.getUsername());
    javaMailSender.setPassword(configuration.getPassword());
    javaMailSender.setHost(configuration.getSmtpHost());
    javaMailSender.setPort(configuration.getSmtpPort());

    javaMailSender.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");

    Properties properties = javaMailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(configuration.getFrom())) {
        properties.put("mail.smtp.from", configuration.getFrom());
    }

    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", configuration.getSmtpPort());
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", false);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
    properties.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.put("mail.debug", configuration.isDebug());

    return javaMailSender;
}
```

just replace configuration calls, with your values.

Comment: Where am I suppose to create this ?

Comment: In SimpleOrderManager constructor